# A challenege on learneroo was.... When the following loop terminates, what will num equal?

Tags: while-loop

A challenge on learneroo was.... When the following loop terminates, what will num equal?

The answer is 12 how do you figure out what the answer is im confused i had to look at the cheats to pass it please help thanks.

```
int num=0;
while(num<10){
num=num+3; 
}
```

Comment: If Learneroo set the challenge then Learneroo should have explained the concepts, either beforehand in preparation, or afterwards as clarification. Either way, I'm a little confused as to why you're asking here. Bear in mind I may be a little biased, since I can't appreciate what you don't know, but that's a while loop: it *tells* you what it's doing.

Comment: Think about what the value of num is during each iteration. Grab a piece of paper and write the value of num out line by line. for each iteration, ask yourself if the while condition passes or fails. Hope this helps.

Comment: David Thomas im just getting started in learning code languages. They did explain in learneroo but not enough for me to understand. I'm a little confused on why you don't understand why im asking the question here its a question and answer site I know its a while loop and im confused on what its doing thanks for your answer though.

Comment: thank you for your answer jmort253 I understand it a little more now thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry that you were confused. The loop body adds 3 to `num` each time it is reached. `num` starts at 0 and then becomes 3, 9 and 12. When `num` hits 12 the loop condition is no longer true, so the loop terminates. I added a hint to that challenge on the [loops page](https://www.learneroo.com/modules/11/nodes/132) to help out.

Comment: Thank you Ari for breaking it down for me I understand it now thanks